# How can I change the working directory when running a docker container?

Tags: docker

I am running a `yarn` command inside node docker container and I'd like to change the working directory on `docker run` command. The current command I am using is:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/$BUILDDIR:/outputs -it --rm node:12.16.2-alpine3.11 cd /outputs;yarn install --only=production --pure-lockfile
```

I got this output:

```
sh: can't open 'cd': No such file or directory
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.13s.
```

It seems that it tries to run `cd` as a script file. How can I change working directory without updating docker image?

Comment: Make sure the `;` isn't being interpreted by your shell, but instead by the shell on the receiving end. You may need to quote the last argument. Consider: `"cd /outputs && yarn ..."`

Comment: If you're just trying to run Node, I'd suggest using an OS package or the download link on the front page of nodejs.org.  Using Docker just to "not need to install" Node adds a lot of unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--workdir` or `-w` instead of trying to `cd`:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/$BUILDDIR:/outputs -it --rm -w /outputs node:12.16.2-alpine3.11 yarn install --only=production --pure-lockfile
```